# how to use since and for in present perfect continuos

Tags: grammar

I have learned that we can use 'since' and 'for' in perfect tenses.

I have been living in london for a
 few years.
or
I have been living in london since few years ago

The point is that using present perfect continuous in a sentence already shows that it is still taking place. and i learnt that we need to use 'ago' with few years, 10 years, etc to make it have a start and end but for present perfect continuous it has already an end ( still taking place) so that means we don't need to put 'ago' in the end?

Comment: You need to look up *since* and *for*. Use [this dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/), for example. This question stems from your not understanding what these two basic words mean.

Comment: The 'since' is very rare in this sense - at least in my experience - except by non-native speakers. I would never have written either of those, preferring "I have lived in London for a few years" or "I have lived in London a few years." Even "have been living" seems out of place for what I think you are trying to say.

Comment: "I have been living in London for a few years", but "I have lived in London since 2010" are both idiomatic.